# apache server status doesn't show cpu usage

Tags: apache

I'm having difficulties getting server-status of Apache server to display the cpu usage.
I enabled `mod_status.co` module and configured `httpd.conf`.

When I open the link http://localhost/server-status it works, shows all statistics, but doesn't show the cpu usage?

My server details are:

> > **Server Version: Apache/2.2.29 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zc
> >
> >     Server Built: Sep 10 2014 11:58:36**

Any ideas? please!!

httpd.conf lines for server-status:

> > `ExtendedStatus On
> >     <Location /openserver/server-status>
> >             SetHandler server-status
> >             Order deny,allow
> >             Deny from all
> >             Allow from 127.0.0.1
> >         </Location>`

Can anyone help me?

This is the screenshot of my server-status, and there is not CPU
[image]

Comment: Can you provide details on what you have set in httpd.conf?

Comment: I've added what you asked

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your httpd.conf for the following line and ensure it's not commented out?

```
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
```

**EDIT** Scratch that..

I believe cpu usage in mod_status does not work on Windows servers.
You might need to look up the mod_lua scripts, or something like phpsysinfo

https://github.com/Humbedooh/server-status

Comment: Yes, the line LoadModule for `mod_status` uncommented.

Comment: Ok, I will look up mod_lua  rigtht now

Comment: Oh sorry, `phpsysinfo` is not which I wanted, I want to analize server status, not system

Comment: Look at the server-status link I included in my answer, it provides an extended version of what mod_status provides, but does work on Windows server platforms

Comment: I even reinstalled server, but still doesn't show, please help, I need it

Comment: @Faradox did you try the scripts provided in the link in my answer? If so, please update your question with a screenshot of what is, and what isn't showing so I can figure out where it's failing a bit better

Comment: Sk93! I didn't use it, because  I have php scripts that I can parse the data from `http://localhost/server-status` I wanna figure out why  there is not CPU usage. Have you found anything about it

Comment: And I cannot attach screenshot becase of I'm new here :-(

Comment: @Faradox then my original answer stands.. cpu load is not available on windows servers via the standard mod_status (read as, mod_status does not fully work on Win32/Win64 servers)

Comment: @Faradox look at what?

Comment: I attached photo, is there CPU

Comment: @Faradox I don't understand? I've already told you mod_status does not support CPU load on Windows servers. You are running on Windows, and as such CPU will NOT show. You need to use the scripts I put in my answer, or give up.